# switching the escape character multiple times in dockerfile

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

If I have this in its own dockerfile it succeeds:

> ```
> # escape=`
>
> # Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.7.1.
> FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1
>
> # Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing below.
> SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
>
> # Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
> ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
>
> # Install Build Tools excluding workloads and components with known issues.
> RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
>     --installPath C:\BuildTools `
>     --all `
>     --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
>     --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
>     --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
>     --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
>  || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0
>
> # Start developer command prompt with any other commands specified.
> ENTRYPOINT C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat &&
>
> # Default to PowerShell if no other command specified.
> CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
> ```

But if i embed this in another dockerfile it fails:

```
FROM openjdk:8-nanoserver as openjdk

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Remoting versions can be found in Remoting sub-project changelog
# https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
ENV SLAVE_FILENAME=slave.jar \
    SLAVE_HASH_FILENAME=$SLAVE_FILENAME.sha1 \
    REMOTING_VERSION=3.23

# Get the jenkins slave jnlp agent jar from public location
RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/$env:REMOTING_VERSION/remoting-$env:REMOTING_VERSION.jar" -OutFile $env:SLAVE_FILENAME -UseBasicParsing; \
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/$env:REMOTING_VERSION/remoting-$env:REMOTING_VERSION.jar.sha1" -OutFile $env:SLAVE_HASH_FILENAME -UseBasicParsing; \
    if ((Get-FileHash $env:SLAVE_FILENAME -Algorithm SHA1).Hash -ne $(Get-Content $env:SLAVE_HASH_FILENAME)) {exit 1};

# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.7.1.
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing below.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

# Install Build Tools excluding workloads and components with known issues.
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --all `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

# escape=\
# do more stuff
```

I get this error: `Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 33: unknown instruction: --INSTALLPATH`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not supported. A parser directive, like the one to change the escape character, is only valid at the top of the Dockerfile. You can't change the parser configuration after the first non parser directive line. That includes the `FROM` line, any comments, and even a blank line. In addition, each directive can only be set once. See the documentation on parser directives for more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#parser-directives